# Joining a record from a single column date range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

```
Person
+---------+-----------+
|  Name   |   Added   |
+---------+-----------+
| Roger   | 2/1/2001  |
| Natalie | 5/5/2001  |
| George  | 6/6/2001  |
| Paul    | 12/5/1999 |
+---------+-----------+

Stage
+-------------+----------+
| Description |  Start   |
+-------------+----------+
| 1           | 1/1/1980 |
| 2           | 4/1/2001 |
| 3           | 6/1/2001 |
+-------------+----------+
```

I want to join Person with stage such that I get the following result.

```
Result
+---------+-----------+--------+
|  Name   |   Added   | Stage  |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| Roger   | 2/1/2001  | 1      |
| Natalie | 5/5/2001  | 2      |
| George  | 6/6/2001  | 3      |
| Paul    | 12/5/1999 | 1      |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

So, the stage 1 matches (added >= 1/1/1980 AND added < 4/1/2001), stage 2 matches (added >= 4/1/2001 AND added < 6/1/2001), stage 3 (added >= 6/1/2001) etc...  This works, but I think it's kind of ugly (and only happens to work because the description is sequential as well).

```
SELECT  person.name,
        person.added,
        (SELECT MAX(description) FROM stage d2 WHERE person.added >= d2.start) description
FROM    person
```

Is there a way to do this in a regular join, and if description were a string rather than a sequential number?  Thanks.

Comment: [xkcd PSA ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a subquery, you could use `row_number()`:

```
select name, added, description
from (
  select p.name, p.added, s.description
    , row_number() over (
        partition by p.name
        order by s.start desc
        ) as rn
  from person p
    inner join stage s
      on s.start <= p.added
) t
where rn = 1
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/SIAUAZ29747

```
with Person (Name,Added_date) as (
  select 'Roger'   , to_date('2001-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all 
  select 'Natalie' , to_date('2001-05-05','yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all 
  select 'George'  , to_date('2001-06-06','yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all 
  select 'Paul'    , to_date('1999-12-05','yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
),
Stage ( Description  , Start_date ) as (
  select 1, to_date('1980-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
  select 2, to_date('2001-04-01','yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
  select 3, to_date('2001-06-01','yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
)
select name, to_char(added_date,'yyyy-mm-dd') added, description
from (
  select p.name, p.added_date, s.description
    , row_number() over (
        partition by p.name
        order by s.start_date desc
        ) as rn
  from person p
    inner join stage s
      on s.start_date <= p.added_date
) t
where rn = 1
order by added_date
```

returns:

```
+---------+------------+-------------+
|  NAME   |   ADDED    | DESCRIPTION |
+---------+------------+-------------+
| Paul    | 1999-12-05 |           1 |
| Roger   | 2001-02-01 |           1 |
| Natalie | 2001-05-05 |           2 |
| George  | 2001-06-06 |           3 |
+---------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: @GurV Thank you for the syntax fix.  It works if you adjust the way you interpret the dates from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy. here is an iso version: http://rextester.com/SIAUAZ29747

Comment: I was just thinking that. That's it then. :)

Comment: LOL. I was also thinking that it should work but why doesn't it. :D

Answer (score 1):

Problems of this type can often be solved with **no joins at all**. Instead, combine the two tables (as illustrated below) with `UNION ALL` and use the `LAST_VALUE()` function:

```
select   name, added, description
from     (
           select name, added, 
                  last_value(description ignore nulls) 
                       over (order by added, description) as description
           from   ( select name, null as description, added
                      from person
                    union all
                    select null, description, start_date
                      from stage
                  )
         )
where    name is not null
order by added, name   --  if needed
;

NAME    ADDED        DESCRIPTION
------- ---------- -----------
Paul    12/05/1999 1
Roger   02/01/2001 1
Natalie 05/05/2001 2
George  06/06/2001 3
```

Big THANK YOU to @MT0 for providing the setup (CREATE TABLE statements).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that joins the rows in `Person` to `Stage` with a 1:1 correspondence (unlike the accepted solution which will join `Person` to multiple rows in `Stage` and then have to filter out the unwanted rows):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (Name,Added) AS
  SELECT 'Roger'   , DATE '2001-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Natalie' , DATE '2001-05-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'George'  , DATE '2001-06-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Paul'    , DATE '1999-12-05' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Stage ( Description  , Start_date ) AS
  SELECT 1, DATE '1980-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2001-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE '2001-06-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT name, added, description
FROM   person p
       INNER JOIN
       (
         SELECT description,
                start_date,
                LEAD( start_date ) OVER ( ORDER BY start_date ) AS end_date
         FROM   stage
       ) s
       ON ( s.start_date <= p.added AND ( s.end_date IS NULL OR p.added < s.end_date ) );
```

**Output**:

```
NAME    ADDED               DESCRIPTION
------- ------------------- -----------
Paul    1999-12-05 00:00:00           1
Roger   2001-02-01 00:00:00           1
Natalie 2001-05-05 00:00:00           2
George  2001-06-06 00:00:00           3
```

Comment: In this case no joins are needed!   {:-)